# Animating camera on specific position

Tags: java, android, google-maps, design-patterns, builder

As per [google developer's guide here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views#moving_the_camera),to animate camera on specific position

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
    .target(MOUNTAIN_VIEW)      // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
    .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
    .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
    .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
    .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

But, in [api reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition.html#CameraPosition(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng,%20float,%20float,%20float)), CameraPosition has already a constructor defined as:

```
public CameraPosition (LatLng target, float zoom, float tilt, float bearing)
```

So, If I write as:

```
  CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition(latLng,9,0,0);
```

or

```
 CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(latLng).zoom(9).build();
```

are they both same or different? Is there any need of using static nested class [CameraPosition.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition.Builder.html) as per reference?

Also, both have same description:

[CameraPosition constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition.html#CameraPosition(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng,%20float,%20float,%20float)):

> Constructs a CameraPosition.

[public CameraPosition build()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition.Builder.html#build()):

> Builds a CameraPosition.

I doubt if there is any difference between words `constructs` and `builds`. Unfortunately, there isn't any information on whole internet about their difference (if exists). Can anyone help please?

**EDIT:**
From comments, someone pointed out that it uses Builder design pattern. Though, I can't understand why it is used here? What is the need of redundant constructor? Can anyone help me to understand better?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

Comment: @Andy Hi..thanks for the reference...can you explain what is the difference between their usage? i'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the terms `Constructor` and `Builder` in java corresponds to the same as the difference between `CameraPosition constructor` and `CameraPosition build()` in Android's Camera API. Here are the basic differences:

- When you want to reduce the number of parameters Builders serve a better purpose than constructors. Constructors tend to have a lot of parameters when it comes to object invocation in a POJO.
- The builder can help indirectly with non-constructor methods by allowing an easier way to build parameters objects that are passed to methods.
- If there are too many parameters out of which some are even null and many of them share the same data type builders should be used.
- IDE's like take advantage of builder by creating an automated new Builder class with refactored code.

All these points can be taken into consideration when writing code for Camera API in android for better and optimized performance.

For code implementation refer to the following [link](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html?null).

Comment: so, for the sake of usage, both are same, but second one is convenient. right?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose the reason why guys at Google did it, is clarity and convenience.

Which of the following is more readable?

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition(latLng, 11.0f, 0, 0);

CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(latLng)
        .zoom(11.0f)
        .build();
```

You don't have to look up the method signature to know what arguments to enter.  Furthermore you don't have to know the default tilt and bearing values.

Comment: so, both are same, but second one is convenient. right?